# What is it called when two attacks cancel each other out?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

If both characters attack at the same time it will often flash orange and cancel out neutrally. Does anyone know if there is a name/term for this?

Comment: "Attacking at the same time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly known as "clashing," or "weapon clash." It is not mentioned in the manual (for Soulcalibur V), but is a feature going back to Soulcalibur II (at least - not sure if it was in Soulcalibur or Soul Edge/Soul Blade).

Comment: FYI: It was in older ones as well. Edge/Blade even had a thing where the two characters push their weapons against each other (while the player rapidly presses buttons). Whichever one wins gets the hit.